# RShiny ggplot function not plotting correct values corresponding to dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following piece of R code and I am trying to plot a series of curves. The curves are being plotted bu the values that are being plotted are incorrect. I have checked what values are calculated and they are not the same as the values that are being plotted.

Code (where data frames are being created):

```
maleHeightCentileDF <-data.frame(Age=numeric(),Values=numeric(),Centile=character())
femaleHeightCentileDF <- data.frame(Age=numeric(),Values=numeric(),Centile=character())
maleWeightCentileDF <- data.frame(Age=numeric(),Values=numeric(),Centile=character())
femaleWeightCentileDF <- data.frame(Age=numeric(),Values=numeric(),Centile=character())


for(i in 1:9)
{
  maleHeightCentileDF<- 
  rbind(maleHeightCentileDF,data.frame(Age=maleLMSData$Months,Values=lmsFunctionToM(maleLMSData$L.ht,maleLMSData$M.ht,maleLMSData$S.ht,zValues[i]),Centile=pValues[i]))
  femaleHeightCentileDF<-rbind(femaleHeightCentileDF,data.frame(Age=femaleLMSData$Months,Values= lmsFunctionToM(femaleLMSData$L.ht,femaleLMSData$M.ht,femaleLMSData$S.ht,zValues[i]),Centile=pValues[i]))
  maleWeightCentileDF<-rbind(maleWeightCentileDF,data.frame(Age=maleLMSData$Months,Values= lmsFunctionToM(maleLMSData$L.wt,maleLMSData$M.wt,maleLMSData$S.wt,zValues[i]),Centile=pValues[i]))
  femaleWeightCentileDF<-rbind(femaleWeightCentileDF,data.frame(Age=femaleLMSData$Months,Values= lmsFunctionToM(femaleLMSData$L.wt,femaleLMSData$M.wt,femaleLMSData$S.wt,zValues[i]),Centile=pValues[i]))
}

maleWeightCentileDF$Centile <- factor(maleWeightCentileDF$Centile, levels = rev(levels(maleWeightCentileDF$Centile)))
femaleWeightCentileDF$Centile <- factor(femaleWeightCentileDF$Centile, levels = rev(levels(femaleWeightCentileDF$Centile)))
maleHeightCentileDF$Centile <- factor(maleHeightCentileDF$Centile, levels = rev(levels(maleHeightCentileDF$Centile)))  
femaleHeightCentileDF$Centile <- factor(femaleHeightCentileDF$Centile, levels = rev(levels(femaleHeightCentileDF$Centile)))
```

Code (where curves are plotted):

```
if(type=="wt")
  {
    if (gender=="Boys")
    {

      childDF <- data.frame(Age=maleChildrenData$Months[maleChildrenData$id==childID], Values=maleChildrenData$weight[maleChildrenData$id==childID])
      plot<-ggplot(maleWeightCentileDF,aes(x=Age,y=Values, label = Centile))+geom_smooth(aes(colour=Centile),linetype='dotdash',se=FALSE)
      plot<- plot+labs(x="Age (Months)",y="Weight (kg)") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,60,5), limits = c(0,60))+scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,30,1), limits = c(0,max(maleWeightCentileDF$Values)))
    }
    else
    {
      childDF <- data.frame(Age=femaleChildrenData$Months[femaleChildrenData$id==childID], Values=femaleChildrenData$weight[femaleChildrenData$id==childID])
      plot<-ggplot(femaleWeightCentileDF,aes(x=Age,y=Values, label = Centile))+geom_smooth(aes(colour=Centile),linetype='dotdash',se=FALSE)
      plot<- plot+labs(x="Age (Months)",y="Weight (kg)") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,60,5), limits = c(0,60))+scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,30,1), limits = c(0,max(femaleWeightCentileDF$Values)))

    }

  }
  else
  {
    if (gender=="Boys")
    {
      childDF <- data.frame(Age=maleChildrenData$Months[maleChildrenData$id==childID], Values=maleChildrenData$height[maleChildrenData$id==childID])
      plot<-ggplot(maleHeightCentileDF,aes(x=Age,y=Values, label = Centile))+geom_smooth(aes(colour=Centile),linetype='dotdash',se=FALSE)
      plot<- plot+labs(x="Age (Months)",y="Height (cm)")+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,60,5))+scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(40,130,by=5), limits=c(40,max(maleHeightCentileDF$Values)))
    }
    else
    {
      childDF <- data.frame(Age=femaleChildrenData$Months[femaleChildrenData$id==childID], Values=femaleChildrenData$height[femaleChildrenData$id==childID])
      plot<-ggplot(femaleHeightCentileDF,aes(x=Age,y=Values, label = Centile))+geom_smooth(aes(colour=Centile),linetype='dotdash',se=FALSE)
      plot<- plot+labs(x="Age (Months)",y="Height (cm)")+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,60,5))+scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(40,130,by=5), limits=c(40,max(femaleHeightCentileDF$Values)))

    }

  }
```

[Graph Outputted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTNTy.png)

[Data that should be outputted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcVbR.png)

The first data point should be (0,4.81) but (0,6.02) (highlighted in graph) is plotted instead.

Any reasons why this could be happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research into the problem, I found that changing the function for plotting the curves from geom_smooth to geom_path fixed the problem. I am not sure why this fixed the problem but the issue has been fixed nonetheless.